# how to select the row with max row number for each partition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Need the row with max row number for the partitioned column(Name) as well as Name columns having null. Can not reverse the order as it does not containing any date and it should be the order as it inserted.

Please provide the possible solutions.

Comment: What in the world does "Can not reverse the order as it does not containing any date and it should be the order as it inserted." mean?   How are you getting the values for ROW_NUMBER currently? You have to be using something to define the order. Without some sample data here this is highly likely going to get closed.

Comment: Can you share your last coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: You should be able to just change the row number `order by someColumn desc`

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    select Key, 
    item_key, 
    Name, 
    Row_Number,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by Row_Number desc) as rn
)
select Key, 
    item_key, 
    Name, 
    Row_Number
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

Note the distinction between Row_Number (the column in your table) and ROW_NUMBER() (the window function we are using to renumber the rows)

Comment: my bad, i missed it. 
The table which was shown the picture is a temp table, the Row_Number  column values i got using the row_number() function

Comment: In that case you have a problem - there is no inherant ordering to rows in a table, unless you add an identity column or something similar to record the order of insertion, you can't guarantee the order. How are you ordering the rows in the existing query?